# Doctrine2 multiple relationships of two entities

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

We're using Doctrine v2.2.1. With YML defined entities.

Here i have 2 entities which are referring to each other with given associations;

```
entities\User:
  type: entity
  table: user
  oneToMany:
    subjectNews:
      targetEntity: entities\News
      mappedBy: subjectUser
      cascade: ["all"]
    actionNews:
      targetEntity: entities\News
      mappedBy: actionUser
      cascade: ["all"]

entities\News:
  type: entity
  table: news
  manyToOne:
    subjectUser:
      targetEntity: entities\User
      cascade: ["all"]
      nullable: true
    actionUser:
      targetEntity: entities\User
      cascade: ["all"]
      nullable: true
```

When i generate the Entity classes according to these definitions, I get an unexpected result in my entities\User php class. Which is like;

```
 /**
  * Add subjectNews
  *
  * @param entities\News $subjectNews
  * @return User
  */
 public function addNews(\entities\News $subjectNews)
 {
     $this->subjectNews[] = $subjectNews;
     return $this;
 }
```

The setter methods in my entities are generated well as expected. But the add methods for entities\User are not generated as expected.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any workaround to this? Or is it related with [the issue referred in the Limitations and Known Issues doc of Doctrine2](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#mapping-many-tables-to-one-entity)?

Peace

Comment: checkout [this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299738/doctrine-symfony-multiple-one-to-many-relations-on-same-model

Answer (score 2):

This is also one of the issues I came across using Doctrine ORM. Eventhough I  don't know an elegant solution for this, I know that you can use get method to get the ORM collection and just add the entity you want. An example would be,

```
$actionNews = $user->getActionNews();
$actionNews[] = new entities\News();
```

Or for the `subjectNews`

```
$subjectNews = $user->getSubjectNews();
$subjectNews[] = new entities\News();
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Works.. But its dirty.. That solution may cause troubles sometimes. For example; EntityManager may not be able to detect a dirty context. I don't know how Doctrine entities actually work, so I will stick with removing the definition from User entity..